# AJAX multiple calls from the same function, some call backs not working

Tags: javascript, ajax, callback

I have multiple dropdowns that each call the following function (passing different arguments)
If I change one dropdown and wait for the response everything is good.
If I change a second dropdown before the first response, It appears as if the first callback is never called. (the data is changed in the database though)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
function fg_insert_pick(element, team_id, tournament_id, pick_number) {
    golfer_id = element.value;
    golfer_name = element.options[element.selectedIndex].text;;
    parent = element.parentNode;
    parent.removeChild(element);
    parent.innerHTML="submitting pick ...";
    path = "'.plugins_url('fantasy-golf/submit/pick.php').'";
    post = "team_id="+team_id+"&tournament_id="+tournament_id+"&pick_number="+pick_number+"&golfer_id="+golfer_id;
    parent.innerHTML="submitting pick ...";

    fg_ajax_request(path, post, function(response) {
        if (response) {
            parent.innerHTML=golfer_name;
        } else {
            parent.innerHTML="Something went wrong, please reload the page";
        }
    });
}

function fg_ajax_request(url, post, callback) {
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange= function () {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
            callback(xmlhttp.responseText);
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("POST",url,true);
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xmlhttp.send(post);
}
//-->
</script>
```

Comment: Is your `parent.innerHTML=golfer_name;` updates the same element, I mean does every dropdown has individual parent element ?

Comment: The drop downs are in a table so each is in a different <td> element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a simple variable scope issue to me. The variables defined inside of your `fg_insert_pick` are being set on the global level, not within the context of your function. So what you're probably seeing is this:

1. `fg_insert_pick` is called. `golfer_name` is set to the element's selected option and `parent` is set to the given element's parent node.
2. The Ajax request is started.
3. Meanwhile, `fg_insert_pick` is called with a different element. `golfer_name` and `parent` are then overwritten according to this element.
4. The Ajax request comes back from the first call, and the callback in `fg_insert_pick` is called. Since `golfer_name` and `parent` live outside `fg_insert_pick`, they now refer to the second element, not the first. Hence, the second element is updated.
5. The Ajax request comes back from the second call. The same thing happens again.

**tl;dr** Add `var`s to the variables set in `fg_insert_pick`.

Comment: Bingo.  I'm new at JavaScript and knew but forgot that not declaring a variable made it global.